# What is the internal mechanism for ending process of multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, signals, centos7, pool

I was curious about some of the mechanics inside the multiprocessing.Pool.For example, I tested the following code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
from time import sleep


def proc():
    while True:
        print(f'{current_process()} is running...')
        sleep(5)


def main():
    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.apply_async(proc)
    pool.apply_async(proc)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When the code runs, there are five processes. The main process's pid is 71190. Then I turned on another terminal, run `os.kill(71190, signal.SIGTERM)` to kill the main process. Then killed three processes, main process and two idle processes, remaining two processes.

Then I added some code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
from time import sleep
import signal


def handler(*args):
    print(f'{current_process()} is killing...')
    raise SystemExit(1)


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)


def proc():
    while True:
        print(f'{current_process()} is running...')
        sleep(5)


def main():
    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.apply_async(proc)
    pool.apply_async(proc)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I run `os.kill(74407, signal.SIGTERM)` again, This time all processes were killed. And the output is:

```
<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)> is killing...
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)> is killing...
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)> is killing...
```

I'm very curious about what happened, I was only killed main process, why did the child process also receive the signal? I used to find out the PID of all processes, and then kill it one by one. I think Pool must have done something internally. Can anyone explain it for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: You did not tag your question with your platform as you are supposed to with questions tagged with `multiprocessing`. I am guessing it is Windows. What I have discovered at least on my Windows desktop with Python 3.8 is that when I call `os.kill` specifying `signal.SIGTERM` as the signal to be sent that even though I have specified a handler for this signal it is *not* being handled -- although it works under Linux. But the error messages I get are a bit different: **BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed**.

Comment: My fault, The platform is Centos 7 and python version is 3.7.6.  The code can only run on Linux. The signal system of Windows is different with Linux.

Comment: Yes, I see now that these processes were forked. I don't know about Centos 7 but on my Debian Unix running under Windows' WSL2 I do not see the above error messages.